# Diskless Nodes boot

Tags: networking, operating-system, cluster-computing, high-availability

I am trying to understand how  Disk less architecture works. I read it on internet and got lot of answers  but still have few questions left .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq8Ub.jpg

[image: configuration]

The two nodes have booted with the operating system image 1

As Systems are running is it possible that I switch to operating system image 2 ? That means systems should not go down.  All the Software working on the machines should continue to work .
** Both the operating system images are from same operating system, example Operating system image 1 and image 2 both are Ubuntu 10.04
So my main question is it possible to switch seamless between operating system images? 
If yes can you give me a brief idea or the link where this thing is explained?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I dont think in most cases you can seamlessly switch between OSes on the same system unless you have something like a virtual box installed.
As for the processes not dying, one possible way that some systems implement would be to migrate them to the other node, update the current node OS and bring them back.